# How to compute length of permutation in symmetric group

Tags: permutations

What is the length of a permutation and how do you compute it? For example what are the permutations in S_4 of length 1?

Comment: There are a few things I could think of as being the "length" of a permutation, but the most natural one is not actually intrinsic to the group, but requires a choice (making the group a Coxeter group). Where did you see the term?

Comment: Good question: what is the length of a permutation?

Comment: Found an article at https://rfgsemisimply.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/length-of-a-permutation/. Still looking at it though.

Comment: So that article defines it in a way intrinsic to the group, but it does not agree with the one I had in mind (which is good to keep in mind if you encounter the term elsewhere). I don't think I have seen the one from that article before.